# SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop when I use it in loop

Tags: python, rect

#### Problem

Hi, I am have a problem. Well, I know that I can't use `break` outside the loop but I use it in loop and still get an error.

#### What I do

I  create a function that have a command `break` and use it in loop. I get an error. I can't do something like this:

```
function()
break()
```

because my function have an `if` statment, for example:

```py
do somthing
if that:
   break
```

#### Code

```py
def destroy():
    i = o.index(rect)
    MAPh[i] -= 1
    if MAPh[i] <= 0:
        del o[i]
        del MAP[i]
        del MAPxy[i]
        del MAPh[i]
        break

for a in range(len(MAP)):
    ...
    destroy
```

Comment: A function can't `break` on behalf of its caller. Control flow statements don't work like that.

Comment: You can call `destroy()` from anywhere, it doesn't have to be from within a loop. That's when the `break` command would cease to make sense. Hence, this simply isn't possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [break and continue in function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13986884/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a function is called from a loop doesn't mean you can break the loop from it. The `break` statement must be ***directly*** in the scope of a loop, not implicitly.

If you want to break the loop when a condition in the function is fulfilled, you can change the function to return an indicator for the loop to break:

```py
def destroy():
    ...
    if condition:
        return True
    return False

for a in range(len(MAP)):
    ...
    if destroy():
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Break or continue are part of loops. You can use them if there is a loop in your code. If you just use conditional statements you can't and you don't need to use break. Just remove it or put your code into loop.